# How to send a notification to all my Facebook application users

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I have a Facebook Android application, and **I need to notify my application users via Facebook when I publish a new update to my Android application, Is that possible? And how?**

Knowing that according to this Facebook documentation I can get my Facebook application to notify a user with a message up to 180 letters (Following the recommended UX), **but here's my other problem**, I don't have my Facebook application users IDs, and of course it would be very hard to manually send a notification to each user (In case I have their IDs, and I don't).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

**To sum my question, does App-to-User notification could achieve what I want or I misunderstood its purpose?**

- P.S: I know you may say, why would you want to notify your users that there's a new application update where Google play will notify them.

Simply, my application and its updates being distributed via different stores and some of them are web based which will not notify the user, plus most of users may not pay enough attention to Google store apps updates notifications as they pay attention to Facebook notifications, along with the fact that users uses Facebook many times a day, while the majority of users will not open Google App Store in a long period.

Comment: You can create a facebook group, and notify followers

Comment: @DimaBabich Thank you for the suggestion, but for sorry this will not be applicable and practical as if there's a notification method as in my question.

Comment: No, you can not do that for with an Android-only app. The app notifications you linked to are for canvas apps only, and they will surface on desktop only as well. Plus, you would still need the users ids to be able to send them in the first place. A group for users to join or an app page to follow would be your best options, if you want to use what Facebook offers “built-in” – if you want more than that, you have to handle it on your end (probably involving a server-side component; some kind of push notifications, or less complicated solutions like f.e. an email newsletter.)